# GROUP BY in SQL Server PIVOT table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

Rows are repeated in the following pivot. Emp Name is repeated thrice as you see in the below image. If I use order by also, got the same result. What mistake I did. How can i get the correct output. Can anyone help me out. (Using SQL Server 2012)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
         e.EmpName, ClaimSource, TicketStatus 
     FROM 
         ClaimMaster c
     INNER JOIN 
         Allocation a ON c.ClaimMasterId = a.ClaimMasterId
     INNER JOIN 
         myUsers..EmpMaster e ON a.AllocatedToEmpId = e.AspUsername
     WHERE 
         TicketStatus IN ('First Review','Calling Pending','Analyst Action','Recalling') 
    ) m
PIVOT (
    COUNT(ClaimSource)
    FOR ClaimSource IN ([Aging Report],[Appeal],[Denied],[Rejected],[Special Project],[Eligibility],[Correspondence])
) n
PIVOT (
    COUNT(TicketStatus)
    FOR TicketStatus IN ([Recalling])
) o
```

[image]

Desired output

[image]

If I remove the `TicketStatus` column & pivot then I can get the desired output.

Comment: `What mistake I did. How can i get the correct output.`  And the *correct* output is *what?*

Comment: give use some test data and an example to play with don't make us create our own?  Also show use what your desired results is.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Comment: @matt added the output image. can u pls tell me how can I show the data here, i have 44 rows

Answer (score 1):

First my suggestion is to use conditional aggregation so you can aggregate both conditions simultaneously.

```
SELECT
    e.EmpName
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ClaimSource = 'Aging Report' THEN ClaimSource END) as [Aging Report]
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ClaimSource = 'Appeal' THEN ClaimSource END) as [Appeal]
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ClaimSource = 'Denied' THEN ClaimSource END) as [Denied]
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ClaimSource = 'Rejected' THEN ClaimSource END) as [Rejected]
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ClaimSource = 'Special Project' THEN ClaimSource END) as [Special Project]
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ClaimSource = 'Eligibility' THEN ClaimSource END) as [Eligibility]
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ClaimSource = 'Correspondence' THEN ClaimSource END) as [Correspondence]
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TicketStatus = 'Recalling' THEN TicketStatus END) as [Recalling]
FROM ClaimMaster c
    INNER JOIN Allocation a ON c.ClaimMasterId = a.ClaimMasterId
    INNER JOIN myUsers..EmpMaster e ON a.AllocatedToEmpId = e.AspUsername
WHERE TicketStatus IN ('First Review','Calling Pending','Analyst Action','Recalling') 
GROUP BY
    e.EmpName
```

You essentially are trying to do 2 different types of aggregation based on ClaimSource and TicketStatus PIVOT cannot do that.  As far as what actually happens Your first Pivot creates the extra rows because it has ticket status still in it.  Then your next pivot that column is pivoted and counted on so it drops it off.  However because all of the other columns exists it doesn't actually perform any aggregation.  I can only assume from your image of the data that your employees there did not have any RecallingTicketStatus.  Instead of pivoting a second time you could do a second round of aggregation:

```
SELECT
    EmpName
    ,SUM([Aging Report]) as [Aging Report]
    ,SUM([Appeal] as [Appeal]
    ,SUM([Denied]) as [Denied]
    ,SUM[Rejected]) as [Rejected]
    ,SUM([Special Project]) as [Special Project]
    ,SUM([Eligibility]) as [Eligibility]
    ,SUM([Correspondence]) as [Correspondence]
    ,COUNT(Recalling) as Recalling
FROM (
    SELECT e.EmpName, ClaimSource, TicketStatus FROM ClaimMaster c
    INNER JOIN Allocation a ON c.ClaimMasterId = a.ClaimMasterId
    INNER JOIN myUsers..EmpMaster e ON a.AllocatedToEmpId = e.AspUsername
    WHERE TicketStatus IN ('First Review','Calling Pending','Analyst Action','Recalling') 
) m
PIVOT (
    COUNT(ClaimSource)
    FOR ClaimSource IN ([Aging Report],[Appeal],[Denied],[Rejected],[Special Project],[Eligibility],[Correspondence])
) n
GROUP BY
    EmpName
```

Or perhaps more easily only do the pivot for ClaimSource and do standard aggregation and a join for Recalling.  But if you do this I would suggest carrying the employee id instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT *
       FROM (
          SELECT e.EmpName, ClaimSource FROM ClaimMaster c
          INNER JOIN Allocation a ON c.ClaimMasterId = a.ClaimMasterId
          INNER JOIN myUsers..EmpMaster e ON a.AllocatedToEmpId = e.AspUsername
          WHERE TicketStatus IN ('First Review','Calling Pending','Analyst Action') 
       ) m
       PIVOT (
          COUNT(ClaimSource)
          FOR ClaimSource IN ([Aging Report],[Appeal],[Denied],[Rejected],[Special Project],[Eligibility],[Correspondence])
       ) n
    ) t
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT
          SELECT e.EmpName, COUNT(TicketStatus) as Recalling FROM ClaimMaster c
          INNER JOIN Allocation a ON c.ClaimMasterId = a.ClaimMasterId
          INNER JOIN myUsers..EmpMaster e ON a.AllocatedToEmpId = e.AspUsername
          WHERE TicketStatus IN ('Recalling') 
    ) t2
    ON T1.EmpName = t2.EmpName
```

To solve this in the future step through each part of your query.  So do it with the 1 pivot look at the result.  With TicketStatus in there you should have raised a flag if you had done this.

Answer (score 0):

If I remove the TicketStatus column & pivot then I can get the desired output.

Comment: but is this the desired output?  you have Recalling column in your result set and you show that you want to count when something is recalling.  If that is the case then simply drop the second pivot and ticket status as you suggest.  If you want the recalling column then read my answer to figure out what is going on